# jquery targeting a adiv in another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the below mentioned code is working perfectly, that when clicking the thumbnail the larger image is opening in a blank window, but i have an html page fprod.html with a 
   `<div id="mainimg></div>`.

I want the image to be open there. Now, how to target the div in that html page?

```
$(function () {

  $(document).on('click', 'div.prodcls img', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('src').replace('images/zara/thumbnails/1.png', 'images/zara/big.png'), '');
  });

});
```

Comment: javascript only has access to the windows that it is defined within or its parent/child windows. You can't access a window that it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the fprod.html in a new window instead of the image. The URL to the image could be provided as a parameter and you could have a javascript in fprod.html put the image in the  you wanted.

```
http://..../fprod.html?image=images/zara/thumbnails/1.png
```

The script in fprod.html could look something like:

```
var img = $("<img/>").attr("src","window.location.search.replace("?","")");
$("#mainimg").append(img);
```

Comment: visit lemonx.biz and click on the zara thumbnail the brown shoes it opens in a new blank page i want to properly settle it there in a div

Answer (score 1):

window.open will return a handle to the newly opened window... you could then call ${window ref}.document.getElementById("mainimg") and populate it with that. (Where ${window ref} is the return value of window.open).

Comment: i dont get it properly will u please make it properly in a code

Comment: This is assuming you are opening a window within the same URL space

Comment: var win = window.open(${usual stuff});
//you'll need a bit of a timeout here to let the window open... so do a setTimeout(function(){
var targetImg = win.document.getElementById("mainimg");}, 1000);

/// the rest of your code

Comment: visit lemonx.biz and click on the zara thumbnail the brown shoes it opens in a new blank page i want to properly settle it there in a div

Answer (score 0):

Javascript for security reasons live in a sandbox. The only toys it can find is in that box (window). Would you like that to work differently - i.e. open up two web pages, one your bank with your details on that page and the other for a fast food restaurant?

Comment: visit lemonx.biz and click on the zara thumbnail the brown shoes it opens in a new blank page i want to properly settle it there in a div

Comment: plz check lemonx.biz and click on the brown zara shoes it opens it in a new blank html what i want is to open the image in a div in fprod.html how to target that specific div in that html that when the image is clciked the fprod.html opens and the image is there in a div –

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about it the wrong way (assuming I understand your requirements correctly).

Assuming that fprod.html is running on the same server and has access to the full size image you are wanting to open I would call the other page with url parameters (e.g. pass the image name you want to open in the url) and then use script to open the relevant image within fprod.html

See the following tutorial for URL parameters in jQuery:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html